# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed in entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity

```
private void FunctionA(int t)
{
    var c=Context.Entities.TableStudent.Where(x => x.StudentBranch ==t).ToList();

using(var db=Context.Entities)
{
   foreach (var q in c)
{
    var cb=Context.Entities.Student...
     .
     .
     .
}
DbContext.Entities.SaveChanges();
}
}
c.ForEach(a => a.Situation=true);
DbContext.Entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I take **DbContext.Entities.SaveChanges();**  line give error.This error is

**The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.**

How can I do it this error.
                    .

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first up, continue reading/learning about `IDisposable`, `using()` blocks, and also naming conventions. You aren't doing yourself any favors by making your code more difficult to understand trying to remember what "a", "c", etc. are, just to save a few seconds typing out a meaningful name.

I'm rather surprised that the code you pasted actually would compile, but without knowing what "Context" is vs. "DbContext" (namespaces, static classes??)...

You're going to have a class which extends EF's DbContext, I'm going to call it "MyContext".. I.e.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
}
```

Inside of this class you'll have DbSets declared, and likely an overridden method `OnModelCreating()` to handle any non-trivial configuration for your entities.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableStudent> Students{ get; set; }
}
```

This class should never be marked as "static".

Then, with your code to manipulate students, related entities and/or other entities where you have DbSets in the DbContext, you will want to scope the lifespan of a DbContext and ensure that all operations against those entities happens within that lifespan. This lifespan is bounded by a `using()` block. Once the code leaves the using block, the DbContext is disposed. This means any lazy load references made by entities *will not work*.

```
using (var myContext = new MyContext())
{
    var students= myContext.Students.Where(x => x.StudentBranch == studentBranch).ToList();

   foreach (var student in students)
   {
     // .. logic...
     student.Situation = true;
   }
   myContext.SaveChanges();
}
// After this point, it is unwise/unsafe to "use" any reference to students.
```

Do what you need to do within the scope of the using block. If you need to pass student data outside, such as to return from a method call, copy the values over to a plain 'ol C# object (ViewModel or DTO) and return that. Accessing Entities outside of the DbContext scope will result in errors because the context that the student was loaded under has been disposed. Even in cases where the scope is kept alive (such as using a Static context [bad!] or scoping the context to the web request with an IoC container, you may avoid errors, but introduce unintended performance problems due to lazy loading.

`SaveChanges` is something that typically only needs to ever be called once within a lifetime scope of a DbContext. When set up to know the relationships between entities, EF will manage associating things like Foreign Keys between entities, even new entities that you create. One common panic point people reach is a chicken & egg scenario where I want to create an entity with children, but the children need the parent ID which won't exist until SaveChanges gets called. As long as the parent and child relationship is mapped properly, EF will resolve this automatically when SaveChanges is called provided the children were added to the parent's children collection. SaveChanges applies to the whole set of operations against entities the DbContext knows about (and their relations) so it's not applied at an entity by entity basis.

This should hopefully get you started on how to incorporate Entity Framework and working with it's disposable nature. DbContexts are designed to be relatively short-lived, constructed and disposed as needed. Normally these will be scoped to live as long as a unit of work, being a web request / action, or similar. Longer-lived DbContexts will result in performance/resource issues due to their tracking and caching nature. (Plus issues when attempting to scope SaveChanges calls, discarding changes, etc.)